# Socket Library Roundtrip time outliers

Tags: c++, sockets, kernel, buffer, flush

I have written a socket library and we are seeing steady roundtrip times form A to B back to A, however every so often we see an outliar that is twice or three times our RT (roundtrip) average.  My colleague believes its an issue with paging, is there any way to prove this?  It would be on thing if we saw rt times with the same spike level each time, however we are seeing the spikes grow in size the longer the application is running.

Does anyone else have any ideas?

For each spike I have noticed that kernel runs this command:
flush-253:0 and kswap0

Ive also noticed vmstat shows the bo increasing in correlation to peak rtt

Comment: Are you using TCP? What do you mean by "paging"? How are you measuring roundtrip times? At application level?

Comment: yes TCP sockets. paging is the kernel swapping memory.  RT times are calculated at application level when a message is received from A, A decodes it and extracts the sendingtime from the message.

Comment: Most likely, the outlier is due to two or three round trips being required (probably to the library using a poor I/O strategy). It would be very hard to imagine how paging would affect TCP round trip time.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean "two or three round trips being required" As well what makes you certain paging is independent of TCP round trip time?

Comment: Im using the best non blocking i/o strategy for linux - epoll, as well I have made it so multiple threads can all asynchronously epoll over same fd array.

Comment: When do you write to the socket though?

Comment: ive noticed the bo from vmstat increases in correlation to spikes in rtt received.  Which falls in line with a possible i/o problem.

Comment: it seems to be caused by an I/O bottleneck, not sure what to do.  May have ti restructure entire library.